# Weak* extreme points

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Suppose $x$ is an extreme point of the unit ball of a Banach space $E$. Embed $E$ in $E^{**}$ in the standard way. Is $x$ an extreme point of the unit ball of $E^{**}$?

Comment: With regard to the title, where does the weak-* topology enter this question?

Comment: The general definition I have in mind is: an extreme point of $K \subset E$ is *weak\* extreme* if it is still an extreme point of the weak* closure of $K$ in $E^{**}$. I guess it's not hard to come up with examples of extreme points that are and that are not weak* extreme.

Comment: Come to think of it, that may be a good way to find a counterexample to my question ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is **no** and $E=\mathscr{K}(\ell_p)$ for $p\in (1,\infty)\setminus \{2\}$ is already a counterexample. See the proof of Proposition 2.3 in

> J. Hennefeld, [Compact extremal operators](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1256049500), *Illinois J. Math.* **21** (1997) 61-65.

Here we identifty $\mathscr{K}(\ell_p)^{**}$ with $\mathscr{B}(\ell_p)$.

This question is discussed in:

> S. Dutta, T. S. S. R. K. Rao, [On Weak-${}^\ast$ Extreme Points in Banach Spaces](http://home.iitk.ac.in/~sudipta/revise.pdf), *Journal of Convex Analysis*, **10** (2003), No. 2, 531-539.

where further examples are given.

Comment: Oh great. That answers it nicely!